# How to tell Bazel to include numpy as a dependency and have Vscode autocomplete work with it?

Tags: python, numpy, visual-studio-code, bazel

The Bazel documentation for Python has not been helpful. I am using Vscode.
Lets say that I have the following Python file:

```
package(default_visibility = ["//visibility:public"])

py_binary(
    name = "LogTest",
    srcs = [ "LogTest.py" ],
    # deps = [
    #      "@numpy",
    # ],
)
```

How exactly do I add numpy to this? And how do i get Vscode to have autocomplete for numpy?

Answer (score 0):

External dependencies are not supported in built-in python rules, but you can a [bazelbuild/rules_python](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_python/tree/master/examples/pip_install) to achieve that.

About autocompletion: I guess it is not possible, you need to treat you bazel project as a regular python project. Even a PyCharm IDE, which is officially supported by a Bazel team does not support external dependencies: there is a bug related to relative import path, which break autocompletion for any external dependency